# Will COM marshalling be (ever) neccessary for an object with ThreadingModel Both?

Tags: c++, com, marshalling, sta, apartments

This is triggered by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297297/which-tags-are-required-in-the-manifest-for-registration-free-com).

Specifically, I have a in process COM class, that is defined in the [CLSID registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as having a [`ThreadingModel` of `Both`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Our process activates this object through [`CoCreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (*not* [`CoCreateInstanceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if that even matters for an in-proc dll server)

Given a threading model of `Both`and given th rules listed in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Threading model of server | Apartment server is run in
------------------------------------------------------
Both                      | Same apartment as client
```

and given what Hans writes in the other answer:

> ... Marshaling occurs when the client call needs to be made on a
>   different thread. ... can happen when the ThreadingModel specified in
>   the comClass element demands it. In other words, when the COM object
>   was created on one thread but is called on another and the server is
>   not thread-safe.

my tentative conclusion would be that such an object will *never* need implicit marshalling of calls to its interfaces, since the object will always live in the same apartment as its client.

Is that correct, even if the client process is running as [STA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Ah. A possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460071/does-it-require-to-marshal-the-com-object-supporting-threading-model-both?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there may be marshaling.

If the client of your COM class is running in an STA and you attempt to invoke your class from another apartment, it will have to marshal to the apartment that it was created in.

The COM terminology can be really confusing. When you refer to a 'client' in this case, you're really referring to a thread, not the entire application (as it would imply).

`Both` just means that the threading model of the server conforms to the client that instantiates it. That is, when you instantiate your class, it takes on the threading model of the thread it was created on. Since you're instantiating the server in an STA, your server will use STA, meaning it can only be invoked on the thread that created it; if another thread tries to invoke it, it will marshal to the thread it was created on.

Comment: ... and if you don't want marshaling in this case either, then mark your object with ThreadingModel=Both and also aggregate the free-threaded marshaler (aka FTS; see `CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler`). Be careful - an object like that pretty much cannot cache any interface pointers (or any other apartment-affine state) unless they are known to also aggregate FTS.

Comment: And of course, no matter what you do, marshaling has to be involved for cross-process and cross-machine calls.

Comment: So, if the client thread is initialized MTA, there will not be any marshalling? And if the STA thread client is the only thread to call into the object there will not be any marshalling either?

Comment: I somehow was under the impression that calling an STA interface pointer from another thread is illegal anyway (unless the user code does explicit marshalling).

Comment: @MartinBa -There's a discussion of this exact issue in Don Box's [Effective COM](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0201379686/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_1?pf_rd_p=1535523722&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0201634465&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=08DPTP1JA7XG7Y9TH93R).

Comment: @Eric - I have Effective COM on my desk - can you give an exact reference?

Comment: @MartinBa - Item 33 (Beware the FTM).

Answer (score 3):

I can't help myself posting this, although it is not a direct answer to the question.

There's a brilliant MSKB article from the golden ages of COM: [INFO: Descriptions and Workings of OLE Threading Models](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150777). Still there, and has all the relevant info. **The point is, you should not worry about whether there is marshaling or not, if you follow the rules**. Just register your object as `ThreadingModel=Both`, aggregate the Free-Threaded Marshaler with `CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler`, and be done. COM will do the marshaling if needed, in the best possible way. Depending on the client's apartment model, the client code may receive the direct pointer to your interface, if it follows the rules too.

Any "alien" interface that you may receive when a method of your interface gets called, will be valid in the scope of the call, because you stay on the same thread. **If you don't need to store it, that's all that matters.**

If however you do need to cache the "alien" interface, the right way of doing this would be to store it using `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`/`CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream`:

To store it:

- Enter critical section;
- call `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` and store the `IStream` pointer in a member field;
- Leave critical section;

To retrieve it

- Enter critical section;
- call `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` to retrieve the interface
- call `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` and store it again as `IStream` for any future use
- Leave critical section;
- Use the interface in the scope of the current call

To release it:

- When you no longer need keeping it, just release the stored `IStream` (inside the critical section).

If the "alien" object is free-threaded too, and the things are happening inside the same process, you will likely be dealing with a direct interface pointer after `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream`. However, you should not make any assumptions, and you really don't need to know if the object your dealing with is the original object or a COM marshaller proxy.

This can be slightly optimized by using `CoMarshalInterface` w/ `MSHLFLAGS_TABLESTRONG` / `CoUnmarshalInterface` / `IStream::Seek(0, 0)` / `CoReleaseMarshalData` instead of `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream`/`CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream`, to unmarshal the same interface as many times as needed without releasing the stream.

More complex (and possibly more efficient) caching scenarios are possible, involving Thread Local Storage. However, I believe that would be an overkill. I did not do any timing, but I think the overhead of `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`/`CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream`is really low.

That said, if you need to maintain a state that **stores any resources or objects which may require thread affinity**, other than aforementioned COM interfaces, you **should not** mark your object as `ThreadingModel=Both` or aggregate the FTM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, marshalling is still possible. A couple of examples:

1. the object is instantiated from an MTA thread and so placed into an MTA apartment and then its pointer is passed into any STA thread and that STA thread calls methods of the object. In this case an STA thread can only access the object via marshalling.
2. the object is instantiated from an STA thread and so placed into an STA apartment belonging to that thread and then its pointer is passed into another STA thread or an MTA thread. In both cases those threads can only access the object via marshalling.

In fact you can expect no marshalling only in the following two cases:

1. the object is instantiated from an MTA thread and then only accessed by MTA threads - both the one that instantiated the object and all other MTA threads of the same process.
2. the object is instantiated from an STA thread and then only accessed by that very thread

and in all other cases marshalling will kick in.

Comment: "... then its pointer is passed into any STA thread ..." : I thought it is illegal to pass an object pointer to another apartment?

Comment: Specifically, [you write in the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3465006/321013) that "... If you just pass a raw pointer then there're no means for how marshalling would turn on ..." and I understand that to mean that unless our code contains explicit marshalling calls for object pointers, we could perhaps inadvertently pass raw pointers to another apartment, but that would be illegal anyway.

Answer (score 1):

ThreadingModel = Both simply means that the COM server author can give a guarantee that his code is thread-safe but cannot give the same guarantee that *other* code he didn't write will be called in a thread-safe way.  The most common case of getting such foreign code to execute is through callbacks, connection points being the most common example (usually called "events" in client runtimes).

So if the server instance was created in an STA then the client programmer is going to expect the events to run on that same thread.  Even if a server method that fires such an event was called from another thread.  That requires that call to be marshaled.